# sqlite query returns incomplete data in executable

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to run the following query on my database:

```
select t.*, c.category from (select t.*, l.CategoryID from (select t.*,
ht.TotalAttachments from (select t.*, s.TaskID as Parent from Tasks45 t
left join Subtasks45 s on t.TaskID = s.SubtaskID WHERE DueDate BETWEEN
'1900-01-01' AND '2099-12-31') t left join (select TaskID,
count(THyperlinkID) as TotalAttachments from HyperlinksTasks group by
TaskID) ht on t.TaskID = ht.TaskID) t left join LinksTasksCategories l
on t.TaskID = l.TaskID) t left join categoriesA c on t.CategoryID =
c.CategoryID order by [Parent] asc, [DueDate] asc, [Priority] desc,
[PecentageComplete] asc
```

This works, when I run my program in the terminal, but once it is compiled into an executable it doesn't work. The executable is 64-bit.
By doesn't work I mean, the rows returned do not contain a 'category' key, which I have in the 'categoriesA' table.

I suspect the join operation to be the cause, but where would I begin looking into this?

Edit: Table definitions are

```
CREATE TABLE LinksTasksCategories (
    TaskID     INTEGER (10),
    CategoryID GUID (36),
    FOREIGN KEY (
        CategoryID
    )
    REFERENCES categoriesA (CategoryID),
    FOREIGN KEY (
        TaskID
    )
    REFERENCES Tasks45 (TaskID)
);

CREATE TABLE categoriesA (
    CategoryID GUID (36),
    category   VARCHAR (50)
);

CREATE TABLE Tasks45 (
    TaskID            INTEGER               PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Subject           VARCHAR (255),
    Description       LONGCHAR (1073741823),
    StartDate         TIMESTAMP (19),
    DueDate           TIMESTAMP (19),
    PecentageComplete BYTE (3),
    Priority          INTEGER (10),
    ReplicaID         GUID (36),
    Cancelled         BIT (1)
);

CREATE TABLE HyperlinksTasks (
    THyperlinkID GUID (36),
    TaskID       INTEGER (10),
    THyperlink   VARCHAR (255),
    TPath        VARCHAR (255),
    FOREIGN KEY (
        TaskID
    )
    REFERENCES Tasks45 (TaskID) 
);
```

Error:

```
if row['category'] is not None:
KeyError: 'category'
```

Comment: What do you mean by *do not contain a 'category' key*?

Comment: after the query, I go through the rows and access each value by its column name, e.g. `row['category']`. This gives me a key error.

Comment: Post the definitions of the tables involved in the query and the exact error message.

Comment: I updated the orignal post. The query I originally posted, was also wrong. It's pretty long and convoluted, but that's what I inherited. I'll try to reduce it, but the question remains: What's the difference between app and terminal?

Comment: As it is your query (although you missed the definition of Subtasks45) should run fine and it returns the column `category`. So I suspect the error comes from your Python code.

Comment: I added some logging and it returns two different dictionaries for terminal and app. In the terminal, everything is there(as expected) but in the built app I only get the fields from the Tasks45 table.

Comment: @forpas OK, new insight: I noticed that for the terminal run, the dictionary contains a 'category' key, which isn't there in the app run. However, the app run has a 'c.category' key. any idea, why that might be?

Comment: You say this works when not compiled- what are you compiling with? Sqlite python lib's using native code behind the python. Once you compile your python to an exe (with whatever tool) you will also be dealing with native code library compatibility and you could get surprising behavior